# Lynx for Windows with OpenSSL and New Color style

Tags: windows, colors, openssl, lynx

I download lynx from [invisible-island](https://invisible-island.net/lynx/)

But the only version that supports OpenSSL (which works great) is the old color styled one
[image: old-lynx-colors]

which I am not used to and is wierd, as I am more used to the new 2006 version (which has black background and blue links)
[image: lynx-new-colors]

so does anyone know how to get the new version with OpenSSL for windows

I heard that cygwin has it but I don't want to install whole Cygwin suite just for lynx

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: Hola LaCalienta!  This is not a specific answer.. but still a good one.  WSL is a game changer.  You will never need to run windows ports of Linux programs again.  You could simply run the version of lynx that comes with the distro you choose to install through WSL.  Cygwin/MingW are ok.. but not great and not native.  Buena suerte.

Comment: yea, for the time being I do not want to upgrade to Windows 10 (when Windows 10 has Aero and Virtual PC 2007 will work on it, then I will upgrade)